# Not all pages are visible in my blogspot

Tags: blog, blogger

I created some pages in my Blogspot but only 3 of them are visible (see the second picture). What do I have to do/change to make it show all the pages I created?

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 1):

In the Layout function, edit your Pages tab.

I suspect that you will find you have chosen to only show selected Pages, and that the three which are ticked are the ones appearing on your blog.  Tick the others, or just select to show all.